# Multithreading - ThreadPool - Android

Tags: java, android

I have an async task going on which calculates data & then the data is copied to the database.
It takes 8hrs to complete my data. while running on the emulator
So I was thinking to use pool-threading so that I can use 6-8 threads at a time so that my data gets calculated in an hour or 2.
So any kind of idea which will help me to reduce the calculation time 
will be highly appreciated

Thanks & Regards
Syed

This is the splash screen activity through which I'm calling async task 
which is in another activity

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private void calculatePath() {
        list = getStationList();
        try {
            calculateRoute();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        StationHelper.getInstance(this).cancelFilling();
    }


    /**
     * This method will get id of all stations from the master table.
     */
    private ArrayList<String> getStationList() {
        ArrayList<String> stationIds = new ArrayList<>();
        MetroDbHelper.getInstance(this).openDataBase();

        MasterTableAPI masterTableAPI = new MasterTableAPI();
        Cursor masterTableCursor = masterTableAPI.getAllStationsData(MetroDbHelper.getInstance(this));

        // fill masterTableData in all stations
        if (masterTableCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                String id = masterTableCursor.getString(masterTableCursor.getColumnIndex(MasterTableAPI.COLUMN_ID));
                id = id.trim();
                stationIds.add(id);

            } while (masterTableCursor.moveToNext());
            masterTableCursor.close();

        }

        return stationIds;
    }

    /**
     * This code will find route between two stations
     *
     * @param fromStationID
     * @param toStationID
     */
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    public void calculateRoute(String fromStationID, String toStationID) {
        if ((i >= list.size())) {
            finishAffinity();
            return;
        }
        if (i != j && i < list.size() && j < list.size()) {
            final StationRoute route = new StationRoute(this, fromStationID, toStationID);

            route.fillDataAsync(new OnFillDataListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(ArrayList<Result> results) {

                    StoreRouteDataHelper.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).insertData(results);

                    ++j;
                    if (j <= list.size() - 1) {
                        System.out.println("Output:: i= " + i + " j=  " + j);
                        calculateRoute();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (j == list.size() && i < list.size()) {
                        try {
                            copyAppDbToDownloadFolder();
                            System.out.println("Output:: 
         copyAppDbToDownloadFolder");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("Output:: 
         IOException");
                        }

                        ++i;
                        j = 0;
                        calculateRoute();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            ++j;
            calculateRoute();
        }
    }
    private void calculateRoute() {
        if (i < list.size() && j < list.size())
            calculateRoute(list.get(i), list.get(j));
    }
```

this is the async task

```
  private class FillDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            calculateRoute();
            fillData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Collections.sort(finalResultList, new 
 ResultComparator(0));
            //filterRoute();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onComplete(finalList);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to try this library, AndroExecutor :

[AndroExecutor](https://github.com/tsuryo/AndroExecutor)

All you need to do is to define 2 tasks, BackgroundTask & UITask.

Comment: Please show some code that provides more detail - that will make it easier for others to understand and use your solution.